# Randomly select two rows in two columns in a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Original dataframe:

```
fruit   Drink     week
banana  milk      Mon
apple   coke      Tue
pear    tea       Wed
```

Second step uses this code: `df['COMBINE'] = df['fruit']+ '+' +df['Drink']`

```
fruit   Drink   COMBINE       week
banana  milk    banana+milk    Mon
apple   coke    apple+coke     Tue
pear    tea     pear+tea       Wed
```

Third step:

Let it randomly select 1 row in the COMBINE column and 1 row in the Week column and then combine them as a string.

Expected result:

```
banana+milk Wed
```

I wonder how to put all the code together?

Comment: Sounds great. Can you share the error you are getting with your code you wrote or share the incorrect output your code produces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off a @piRSquared's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53124627/8146556) and accounting for your new requirements in your edited question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['banana','apple','pear'], 'Drink': ['milk','coke','tea'], 'week': ['Mon','Tue','Wed']})

df['COMBINE'] = df['fruit'] + '+' + df['Drink']

' '.join(df[['COMBINE','week']].apply(np.random.choice).values)
```

Yields:

```
apple+coke Mon
```

Answer (score 4):

#### `numpy.random.choice`

```
df.apply(np.random.choice)

Food    milk
week     Tue
dtype: object
```

Comment: `' '.join(df.apply(np.random.choice).values)`, since it appears the OP wants to combine them into a single string. Good answer!

Comment: @rahlf23 I added more requirement to my question, please help. Thank

Comment: I have added an answer, but you really should not change your requirements after someone has already answered your original question.

Comment: @rahlf23 my bad